# Assign one dataframe column values to another by common column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframe, df1, df2 like below.
**df1:**

```
   A   B    C
0  4  40  300
1  2  70  900
2  5  80  900
```

and another dataframe **df2:**

```
   A  D   E
0  1  0  00
1  2  0  00
2  3  0  00
3  4  0  00
4  5  0  00 
5  6  0  00
```

Now I want to assign the values of column df1['C'] to df2['E'] by the condition where column A matches. The result should be

```
   A  D   E
0  1  0  00
1  2  0  900
2  3  0  00
3  4  0  300
4  5  0  900 
5  6  0  00
```

How can I do this?

**Note:** I am looking for something like update df2 instead of merge, because I have to do this multiple time in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to use merge function.

```
df2 =pd.merge(df2,df1,on='A',how='left')
df2 = df2.fillna(value='00')
df2 = df2[['A','D','C']].rename(columns={'C': 'E'})
print(df2)
   A  D    E
0  1  0   00
1  2  0  900
2  3  0   00
3  4  0  300
4  5  0  900
5  6  0   00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.merge()

```
pd.merge(df2[['A','D']],df1[['A']].assign(E=df1.C),on='A',how='left').fillna('00')

Out[269]: 
   A  D    E
0  1  0   00
1  2  0  900
2  3  0   00
3  4  0  300
4  5  0  900
5  6  0   00
```

Or you can use df.update()

```
df2_new = df2.set_index('A')
df2_new.update(df1.assign(E=df1.C).set_index('A'))
df2_new.reset_index()
Out[254]: 
   A  D    E
0  1  0   00
1  2  0  900
2  3  0   00
3  4  0  300
4  5  0  900
5  6  0   00
```